# Note 20 Ultra, deleted files

Tags: samsung, data-recovery

I lost the ability to post on the other form of this question.

If the bottom comment is right and there is 0 chance of decryption or rooting the deleted data, how do police do forensic downloads?

Does the Samsung Note 20 Ultra have discard enabled by default? And if an app DB was deleted over 2 months ago, is this recoverable?

I know that Android trims/discards every 3 days, but I also assume it depends on whether the file system is set up for this. I need to recover deleted chats from an app that was uninstalled over 2 months ago then reinstalled from the secure folder. I have the PIN, so would data recovery be possible?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129055/discussion-on-question-by-check-note-20-ultra-deleted-files).